# In SQL command some rows misses the update

Tags: sql-server

I'm using ADO.NET with SQL Server 2019 Express to update the stock column in a table `Products` in a for next loop.

My problem is that sometimes one or more rows miss the update in the same loop when the command is executed from remote computers.

My code looks like this:

```
Dim comm as new sqlcommand("update products set stock = round(stock + @q, 3) where code = @code", sqlconn)

'Qtable contains code and quantity of bought products

Sqlconn.open

For i as integer=0 to qtable.rows.count-1

  Comm.parameters.add(@code, sqldbtype.varchar).value = qtable.rows(i).item(0)

  Comm.parameters.add(@q, sqldbtype.double).value = qtable.rows(i).item(1)

  Dim c as integer= Comm.executenonquery()

  Do while c=0
    Threading.thread.sleep(500)
    c = Comm.executenonquery()
  Loop

  Comm.parameters.clear()

Next

Sqlconn.close
```

If anybody could help, I'll be thankful.

Comment: Doing this in a loop is highly inneficient RBAR and susceptible to race-conditions, just pass the data table as a TVP and do a single set-based update

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm searching such solution but could you tell me more about TVP ?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea about it, you can generate a random number and then enter it in the current row you are updating, then before entering the next row, get the previous random value and check that it is the same as your number so if there is a problem and the previous record is not saved for any reason you will find a difference in the random number

Comment: Let me give a real example. qtable contains 30 rows after the update operation, i did a check and i found that the 7th row and the 26th one had missed the update.